# What's the elegant way to get filename that contains more than one dot in python

Tags: python, string

I need to process linux file with multiple parts in the name like:

abc.def.gh.bz2

bz2 is the real extension, I need to get abc.def.gh

Can anyone tell me an elegant way to do this in python?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `os.path.splitext`:

```
import os.path
os.path.splitext("abc.def.gh.bz2") # -> ("abc.def.gh", ".bz2")
```

Comment: yes it is, I didn't test out all the replies, this is the one I used and it is working, thanks to every reply

Answer (score 3):

This one uses [`rsplit()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html):

```
s = "abc.def.gh.bz2"
print(s.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
# abc.def.gh
```

Answer (score 3):

[`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) does just what you want. It returns a tuple with the filename and the extension. Use `[0]` to get just the filename.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('abc.def.gh.bz2')[0]
'abc.def.gh'
```

Comment: I didn't test out all the replies, this is the one I used and it is working, thanks to every reply

Answer (score 2):

- `.rfind()` to find the last dot.

e.g `"abc.def.gh.bz2".rfind(".")` would find the index of the last dot

Any dot below that index would not often* be indicator of filetype. So you could then do e.g `filename = "abc.def.gh.bz2"[:"abc.def.gh.bz2".rfind(".")]` which should slice away the extension, making filename to be a string of `abc.def.gh`

***Though, keep in mind that in some cases e.g *tar.gz* or *gh.bz2* should perhaps be counted as filename extensions. So keep in mind that *`what is a filename`* is a rather fleetly subject**

*Using `import os.path.splitext` is no guarantee at all to getting the "filename". and all it will do is slice the **.** extension from the string passed to it*

Answer (score 0):

The output removes the dots.

```
a = "abc.def.gh.bz2"
parts = a.split(".")
result = ""
sep = ""
for i in range(len(parts)-1):
    result = result + sep + parts[i]
    sep = "."
```

print result

Answer (score -2):

All you need is the `split` function.

```
a = "abc.def.gh.bz2"
print a.split(".")
```

So the full solution you need is

```
a = "abc.def.gh.bz2"
parts = a.split(".")
result = ""
for i in range(len(parts)-1):
  result += parts[i]

print result
```

Comment: this returns a list not the desired output

Comment: downvoters, please explain yourselves.  This is a working solution.